# Install Webservice Datasource in JasperReports Server

Tags: datasource, jasperserver

I am actually new to JasperReports Server, I need to install the WebService Datasource, I know that I should add some files already downloaded in the folder WEB-INF located in the JRS installation folder, but I don't know which folder since there are many named WEB-INF.

Please, tell me if you have any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Edit-------

After copying files, I got the following exception:

```
2016-05-25 11:09:46,143 ERROR JNDIResourceProvider,localhost-startStop-2:75 - error closing context
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Le Contexte est en lecture seule
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.checkWritable(NamingContext.java:960)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.close(NamingContext.java:760)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.JNDIResourceProvider.close(JNDIResourceProvider.java:72)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.CompositeResourceProvider.close(CompositeResourceProvider.java:56)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.initialize(ResourcesFactory.java:163)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<init>(ResourcesFactory.java:92)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactory.<clinit>(ResourcesFactory.java:89)
    at com.tonbeller.tbutils.res.ResourcesFactoryContextListener.contextInitialized(ResourcesFactoryContextListener.java:23)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1721)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Edit-----------------

I got thie following exception:

```
25-May-2016 13:29:56.349 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'queryLanguagesPro' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.util.spring.AbstractBeanPropertyProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractBeanPropertyProcessor.java:59)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.util.spring.GenericBeanUpdater.postProcessBeanFactory(GenericBeanUpdater.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:679)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1721)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

25-May-2016 13:29:56.469 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.war.util.SpringBeanServletContextPlublisher
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'queryLanguagesPro' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:575)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.util.spring.AbstractBeanPropertyProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(AbstractBeanPropertyProcessor.java:59)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.common.util.spring.GenericBeanUpdater.postProcessBeanFactory(GenericBeanUpdater.java:78)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:679)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1721)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that you have seen [the docs](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/installing-webservice-datasource):

> The unzipped folder will be referenced as **[WS_DS_DIR]** from now on.
>
> ### Install in JasperReports Server
>
> 1. Localize your JasperReports Server (JRS) web application folder. We'll reference it as [JRS_DIR] from now on
> 2. Open the folder [WS_DS_DIR]\JRS\WEB-INF
> 3. Copy all the folder's content
> 4. Stop your web server running JRS
> 5. Open the folder [JRS_DIR]\WEB-INF
> 6. **Backup this folder before executing next step!**
> 7. paste the previously copied files. Please note that it is not supposed to override any existing file.
> 8. Start your web server running JRS

Your web application folder is the folder where the server app gets deployed into. So on e.g. Linux and Tomcat this could look like:

`/opt/jasperreports/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver`

Relative to that path you have to follow the instructions. This means the following path would be the one you are looking for:

`/opt/jasperreports/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF`

Make sure to execute especially step 6 if your configuration is different.

**EDIT**

According to the stack trace, there seems to be a problem with another component called `com.tonbeller.tbutils.res`. Someone else had [this problem](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/822153/error-closing-context), too:

> Try adding a file named resfactory.properties under WEB-INF/classes containing the following line:
>
> tbeller.usejndi=false

Then check the logs again, the error should be gone.

** EDIT **

Assuming you are using the community edition of Jasper Server v6.2, there seems to be an incompatibility between the community edition and the data source [as seen here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/web-service-data-source/issues/6661):

> I've also got it on 6.2 - changing "queryLanguagesPro" to "queryLanguagesCe" inside the package removes the error and allows starting of the server, and publishing of the report from Studio to Server. However, you get an error when running the report on the server (stack below). This looks like there is a dependency of the Pro fork that is incompatible with the Community version.

Unfortunately, it seems that the data source is not compatible with your Jasper Report Server version and cannot be used. Your installation seems fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I guess the problem is with step 6, I didn't do the backup so it didn't work. Is It NECESSARY to do this step? Thank you

Comment: Can you please show me how to execute step 6? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, of course there is no connection between the backup and the install. Backing up your files is as simply as copying them somewhere else. Just in case if it didn't work you can copy the whole folder back. But: no files should have been overwritten. Did you make sure of that? Then you could compare the files and delete those which are part of the data adapter. This time, backup the folder first. Then try installing again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are already the 'lib' and 'bundles' folders in [WS_DS_DIR]\JRS\WEB-INF, so I copied the content of [JRS_DIR]\WEB-INF\lib in [WS_DS_DIR]\JRS\WEB-INF\lib, and [JRS_DIR]\WEB-INF\bundles in [WS_DS_DIR]\JRS\WEB-INF\bundles, and copied the rest in [JRS_DIR]\WEB-INF but it didn't work.

Comment: WS_DS_DIR needs to remain untouched. This is just the source folder and should be somewhere else. Try installing the adapter to a new install of JRS to find out if something went wrong

Comment: You did restart the server, didn't you?

Comment: Yes, I am very sorry, I meant " I copied the content of  [WS_DS_DIR]\JRS\WEB-INF\lib in  [JRS_DIR]\WEB-INF\lib, and [WS_DS_DIR]\JRS\WEB-INF\bundles in  [JRS_DIR]\WEB-INF\bundles, and copied the rest in [JRS_DIR]\WEB-INF but it didn't work"

Comment: How do you make sure that the server doesn't have the installed Data Adapter in place?

Comment: It shows me this: Etat HTTP 404 - /jasperserver

type Rapport d''état

message /jasperserver

description La ressource demandée n''est pas disponible.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.14

Comment: Please have a look into `[JRS_DIR]/logs` and check `catalina.yyyy-MM-dd.log` and `localhost.yyyy-MM-dd.log` where `yyyy-MM-dd` is the most current date. Update your question with the newest exception.

Comment: OK, from What I understood , It's impossible to install the webservice datasource, I need to have the Pro version of JasperReports Server to work with the WebService Datasource. Thanks you so much for your help.

Comment: I used another version of the webservice datasource (v0.7), and It worked. Thanks again.